# Dependency injection error using custom annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, cdi, inject

I am trying to initialize a bean based on annotation parameters using the below code in springboot application. But I am getting no qualifying bean error. Any idea what might be the issue ?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [DemoClient] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject(), @DemoAnnotation(name=demo)}
```

Custom Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface DemoAnnotation {
    String name() default "";
}
```

Interface

```
public interface DemoClient {
}
```

Impl

```
public class DemoClientImpl implements DemoClient {
}
```

Factory

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

public class DemoClientFactory {        
    @Produces
    public DemoClient createDemoClient(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        DemoAnnotation demoAnnotation = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(DemoAnnotation.class);
        if (demoAnnotation != null) {
            System.out.println("NAME " + demoAnnotation.name());
        }
        // can return different Impl's based on annotation parameter 'name'
        return new DemoClientImpl();
    }
}
```

Test

```
@Inject
@DemoAnnotation(name = "demo")
private DemoClient demoClient;
```

Comment: This is Java EE not Spring, I will delete my answer.

Comment: You seem to have Spring jars (and configuration) in your application. Are you actually using the Spring Framework anywhere?

Comment: You are mixing up 2 stuff, spring framework, and CDI.

Comment: I am using spring framework too. Is there a spring framework based solution ?

Comment: for spring, the equivalent of CDI `@Produces` is `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class.

Comment: For JEE, your demo annotation should be @Qualifier and the producer method should be annotated with the same demo annotation as the injection target, so that the container can match the two.